# Is this type casting or some kind of pointer arithmetics?

Tags: c++, pointers, casting

I came across a line of code written in C++:

```
long *lbuf = (long*)spiReadBuffer;
```

And it turns out that "spiReadBuffer" is a byte array with 12 elements. But I am a little confused. I think I am familiar with defining pointers and I can see that "lbuf" is a type "long" pointer. Also I thought for casting we can do something like this:

```
y = (int) x;
```

But what if I put a "*" after the "int" just like my first example, where there is one after "long"?
I apologize if this is a really trivial question, but as I went through the type casting and pointers topics I did not come across my case and I did not really understand it.
I would appreciate it if you could guide me or introduce me to any relevant materials or resources.

Comment: Yes, it's a type cast. What is `y`? I suppose it's an `int`.

Comment: How is `y` declared? Suppose it was `long *y` -- what *type* should it *point to*?

Comment: With this type of cast one can access `uint8_t spiReadBuffer[12];` as if it was `uint32_t buffer[3];`, i.e. 32 bits at a time. As for now, it doesn't have any arithmetic.

Comment: When programming in c++ try avoiding c-style casts. C++ casts are more verbose but they tell you what is happening.

Comment: The asterisk (`*`) makes the type a pointer. `long` is an integer type, `long*` is a pointer to that integer type.

Comment: `long *lbuf` is the same as `long* lbuf` - maybe this is the source of your confusion?

Comment: y is an int in the second example not a long.

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen actually you cannot, that would violate the strict aliasing rule.  It could be used to write to malloc'd space however.

Comment: So, what is the point of such declaration anyways? I thought  based on what Aki Suihkonen said, I am pointing to an array (using "long *lbuf) which has 12 bytes in it, two bytes at a time, right?

Comment: @MattMcNabb: We can make that `uint8_t __attribute__ ((aligned (4))) spiReadBuffer[12];` or `union { uint32_t dummy; uint8_t spiReadBuffer[12]; }`

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen union aliasing is illegal in C++, and alignment is a separate problem to strict aliasing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called *type punning*. It tricks the compiler into reading the memory occupied by an object as if it was of another type.

In your case, the array `spiReadBuffer` decays to a pointer to its first element, then the pointer is cast and stored. When you dereference this pointer, you will access the beginning of the array as if it were a `long`.

The problem with this approach is that it triggers undefined behaviour (see *strict aliasing*). So even though it works in a lot of situations, it can also break without notice.

There are two ways (that I know of) to type-pun safely. The first one is standard-compliant : `std::memcpy`.

```
char spiReadBuffer[12];
long rbAsLong;
std::memcpy(&rbAsLong, &spiReadBuffer, sizeof rbAsLong);
// rbAsLong contains the first four bytes of spiReadBuffer, reinterpreted as a long.
```

The second one involves an extension that is often provided by compilers (but you should check), that extends the behaviour of unions.

```
union {
    char buf[12];
    long asLong;
} spiReadBuffer;
```

The standard states that writing to a member of a union then reading from another member is undefined behaviour. These compiler extensions choose to define it as a safe reinterpretation.

Answer (score 0):

in C/C++ arrays are treated the same way by  the compiler:

```
char  spiReadBuffer[12];
char* pBuffer;
```

the compiler will treat both spiReadBuffer and pBuffer as pointers.

The code snippet

```
long *lbuf = (long*)spiReadBuffer;
```

is an example of type casting, only it's for pointer types. A char* is converted to a long*; You could say this is a type of pointer arithmetic because now, you can read sizeof(long) bytes from `spiReadBuffer` using the long* ( instead of one byte at a time ).

The second snippet you showed : `y = (int) x;`  is also a cast, but not for pointers;

Comment: did you mean to write `char* pBuffer;` ?

Comment: *the compiler will treat both spiReadBuffer and pBuffer as pointers.* - Nope. Arrays are not pointers, and pointers are not arrays.

Comment: @Quentin while this is true about pointers and array, from the compiler's point of view they are both one continuous block of memory (even if the size is one  byte) and the code generated is the same: load address, read/write from/to address, increment address.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this snippet:

```
char spiReadBuffer[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
long *lbuf = (long*)spiReadBuffer;
printf ("%08x\n", lbuf[0]);
```

It will print `04030201` on a little endian architecture or `01020304` on a little endian architecture.

After the `long *lbuf = (long*)spiReadBuffer` statement `lBuf` points to the beginning of the `spiReadBuffer` and `lbuf[0]` (or `*lBuf`) allows you to read the first 4 bytes of `spiReadBuffer` as a long.

Comment: Wow!! Very thorough answers by Quentin, Chaker Mallek, Pandrei and Michael Walz. So just to make sure that I have understood this correctly, " (long*)" segment of the code casts the first four bytes of the "spiReadBuffer" into a "long" variable which has four bytes. These four bytes are pointed to buy a four byte pointer named "lbuf".

Comment: @Jamycodes Credit to whom credit is due: Chaker Malleks answer to which you are referring (which seems to be deleted for good reasons) was actually by Prateek Joshi and can be found [here](http://prateekvjoshi.com/2014/08/02/what-is-pointer-casting/)

Comment: @Jamycodes :  " (long*)" segment of the code casts the first four bytes of the "spiReadBuffer" into a "long" variable which has four bytes: not quite. `(long*)  casts the `spiReadBuffer` which is of type `char *` (pointer to char) to a `long *` (pointer to long).